# How do i implement an exception for my "Send Mail" script? (Using "Mail" Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rubygems, sendmail

I`ve written an SendMail script in basic Ruby and it works very well. The problem is if the script sends to an eMail address like "notavliable1" i get the SMTP error that the receipt is not reachable and the script stops.

I need an exception to filter or an REGEX for the Mailaddress.

Here is the snippet:

```
require 'mail'

mail = Mail.new do
      from 'peter@lustig.de'
      to ("#{send.toAdress}")
      subject ("#{send.subject}")

      html_part do
        content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        body ("#{send.body}")
      end
    end
```

How do i tell my snippet to skip an invalid "send.toAdress" ?

I´am using the 'mail' gem.

Answer (score 0):

Using an exception is probably the best practice, since a REGEX will not find every possible error in a mail address.

I have no knowledge of the specific gem, but if a regex solution will do, you could add

```
require 'mail'

mail = Mail.new do
      from 'peter@lustig.de'
      to ("#{send.toAdress}")
      subject ("#{send.subject}")

      html_part do
        content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        body ("#{send.body}")
      end
    end if send.toAdress.match /regex_to_match_email/
```

As for the `/regex_to_match_email/`, I think it's a matter of taste. I usually use this one

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

however, it is far from perfect.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i think i need an exception. The script needs to run a lot of time without erros.